# Is it legal to preferentially hire female nurses & doctors because female patients are less comfortable with men seeing them naked?

Tags: employment, australia, sex-discrimination

Sort of a follow-up to [Is it legal to preferentially hire men instead of women because women can get pregnant?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48042/is-it-legal-to-preferentially-hire-men-instead-of-women-because-women-can-get-pr)

The idea is, women tend to be less comfortable with men seeing them naked than men are with women seeing them naked. Therefore, if I'm operating a hospital/clinic where nudity might be necessary, it's preferable for my patients' comfort to hire female nurses & doctors. Concretely, if I need an electrocardiogram performed, if I have female nurses then all my patients will be relatively comfortable; but if I have male nurses then my male patients will be fine but my female patients will not be so comfortable.

The answer in the linked question says it's legal if:

> (2) (a) the duties of the position can be performed only by a person having particular physical attributes (other than attributes of strength or stamina) that are not possessed by persons of a different sex from the relevant sex;

However this sounds ambiguous to me: both men and women can perform electrocardiograms, but only women can do it such that female patients are comfortable.

Comment: The specifics of anti-discrimination laws vary a lot around the world, and so do cultural standards of what kind of interaction a person is expected to be comfortable with in a medical setting. You might want to add a jurisdiction.

Comment: Australia, then, since that's where the quoted law comes from.

Comment: Does your clinic only or predominantly service females?

Comment: @user6726 we can assume it has both male and female patients.

Answer (score 2):

### No

If you are a hospital, medical practice  etc. Being male or female is not an intrinsic requirement of a doctor or nurses job.

### Yes

If you are an individual hiring care within your own reference because Australian sex discrimination law specifically excludes that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is **yes**, i.e. it is legal.

[Section 30 of the Australian 1984 Sex Discrimination Act](http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/sda1984209/s30.html) discussing when it is lawful to discriminate based on sex:

> (g)  the occupant of the position is required to enter areas ordinarily used only by persons of the relevant sex while those persons are in a state of undress; or

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an incorrect reading.  The "relevant sex" clause refers to when you can hire people of a particular sex.  This clause is saying that you can hire men preferentially if the job involves going into a space where men are undressed, and similarly for women.  It's **not** saying that you can hire women only if the job requires going into some spaces where men are undressed and some spaces where women are undressed.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you could certainly be right. I genuinely don't know the answer to the question in the OP.